# page not refreshing after clicking delete button

Tags: php

good day

need some help here, my Delete button works but page is not automatically refreshing after i clicked the delete button. i still need to manually retrieve the data from db and it would reflect that data is deleted already...

here is my code for delete php: how can i make this to refresh the page automatically?

```
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
    $idtodelete = "'" . implode("','",$id) . "'";


    $query = "DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ticket in (" . $idtodelete . ")";
    $myData = mysql_query($query);
    echo "DATA DELETED";

    if($myData)
    {
    header("Location: delete.php");
    }

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
```

Comment: When pressing the delete button you want to display just the "DATA DELETED" right?

Comment: I believe you have a error with echoing then using header function.

Comment: Are you using ajax to delete?

Answer (score 0):

if you use post method better with this

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $id         = $_POST['id'];
    $idtodelete = "'" . implode("','",$id) . "'";
    $query      = "DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ticket in (" . $idtodelete . ")";
    if (mysql_query($query))
    {
      header("Location: delete.php");
    } else {
      echo "Can not delete";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't set header _after_ data has been send to the output buffer. Doing a `echo` _before_ `header();` is wrong in all ways. Doing the `echo` _after_  `header();` makes no sense either because it shall not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest fetching the data after your delete logic. Then  the delete logic will be executed before fetching the tickets.
Then a redirect to the same page isn't even necessary.

```
//
// DELETE
//
if (isset($_POST['delete'] && isset($_POST['id'])) {
     // Do delete stuff, 
     // notice delete variable which would be the name of the delete form button e.g.
     // If you like, you can still echo "Data deleted here" in e.g. a notification window
}
//
// FETCH data
//
$query = "Select * FROM tbl";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on one of the comments, and on the php documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php :

**Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.**

Basically you have to take out the :

```
echo "DATA DELETED";
```

What's the point to try to echo that string if the page is going to be redirected anyway?

If you want to make it fancy you could use Ajax to delete it, and trigger a `setTimeout()` on JavaScript x seconds after showing the message.

Or if you really really really really, REALLY, want to do it this way, you could disable the errors report/display (using `error_reporting(0)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off')`. By experience I know that it will work, but it's nasty and **extremately ultra highly not recommended**

Comment: the reason why i want to redirect is because my query page which gets data from db is another php...so i want it to redirect there hoping that it would do another query but this time...without the deleted data...if that makes sense...

Comment: Makes sense, it's ok if it's a personal thing, but as how things are out there nowadays the correct way would be using Ajax, using a redirect would look unprofessional. If you really want to work in this you should always learn all the latest trends, there is a lot of competition out there my friend.

Comment: i havent used ajax yet...would u be able to give me a sample code so page would refresh without the deleted data already...then ill work from there?

Comment: would be very extensive, I can't write the full code right now but tell you the logic, it involves some knowledge of Javascript. 1: a php page which deletes the row and returns an Deleted or OK Message. 2: a php page with the new query. 3: a presentation page with the delete button which will call (with ajax) the delete.php, and if the message returned is OK then shows a message and calls the new query page, and return the value from it. Use jQuery, it will ease your life and look for some jquery-ajax tutorial